# HIbernate org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, named-query

Hi don't understand the problem with namedQuery

```
<query name="updtae.payment.paymentDate.by.txn_id">
    <![CDATA[
    update Payment p set p.paymentDate =:payDate WHERE p.txnId=:txnId]]>
</query>
```

getting exception 
HIbernate org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries

no columns same us entity Name 
It works fine in local And don't on production server

getSession().getNamedQuery("updtae.payment.paymentDate.by.txn_id").setTimestamp("payDate",paymentDate ).setString("txnId", txnId).executeUpdate();

Here is call of named query.

Comment: How you are calling ur named query in Java code??Please post some more code.

Comment: In your posted code -- `getSession().getNamedQuery("updtae.payment.paymentDate.by.txn_id").setTimestamp("payDate",paymentDate ).setString("txnId", txnId).executeUpdate();` -- you mispell update

Comment: @hd1 mispell on update is in java code as well as at named query too. So that  is not problem.

Comment: For this sort of thing, I prefer Hibernate's Criteria api, rather than HQL

Comment: Using Criteria  min get list and update each row in cycle that is not right in terms of performance it looks like hibernate version problem. The thing is i cant change version in production serve. All this  works just fine in my local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix problem buy changing hibernate version
from  Hibernate-Version: 3.0.5
to    Hibernate-Version: 3.2.1.ga